# Ecto for Elixir: Foreign Key

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a user profile model with the following schema:

```
  schema "user_profiles" do
    field :birthday, Ecto.Date
    field :gender, :string
    field :first_name, :string
    field :last_name, :string
    field :description, :string
    field :username, :string

    # Associations
    belongs_to :user, User

    timestamps
  end
```

I also have a location model with the following schema:

```
  schema "locations" do
    field :name, :string
    field :admin_1, :string
    field :admin_2, :string
    field :country, :string
    field :country_abbreviation, :string
    field :code, :string
    field :latitude, :decimal
    field :longitude, :decimal

    timestamps
  end
```

A location is a city like Paris, France. Many user profiles can be associated with the same location.  But a location doesn't really need to be aware that user profiles exist.

I want to add a location association to the user profile schema.  I do not want to user has_one because the relationship is not one-to-one. I do not want to add any associations on the location schema to user profile, either.

I have looked at the documentation for Ecto and I am at a loss for how to express this association.

I have consulted the following page:
https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html

I am probably missing something basic but I did try more than a few things before asking this question.

Comment: Sounds like you want a many_to_many association. This means that the user can have many locations and the location can belong to many users. This is typically done through a joins table which would be called e.g. `location_profiles`. Here is a link that goes into more detail: [link](http://learningwithjb.com/posts/many-to-many-relationship)

Comment: @HarrisonLucas Thanks for the comment.  I actually want just to have one location per user profile. And one location can "belong to" many user profiles.  In the database, location is just a foreign key on the user profile table.

Comment: ah right in that case why not just do a a Has_many and belongs_to? E.g. Profilea belongs to locationa and Profileb belongs to locationa. 

Therefore, location has_many profiles, and a profile belongs to a single location?

Comment: @HarrisonLucas If that's the case, do I have to add a foreign key to my location table in the database?

Comment: see below for my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to do a simple has_many and belongs_to relationship between the two models where the profile will belong to a relationship.

This relationship will mean that a location can have many profiles associated with it, whereas a profile can only have one location.

E.g.

> Works:
>
> Profile1:London √
>
> Profile2:London √
>
> Wrong:
>
> Profile1:London X
>
> Profile1:France X

This is how you would go about implementing it.

```
#web/models/location.ex
schema "location" do
  has_many :profiles, MyApp.Profile
end

#web/models/profile.ex
schema "profile" do
  belongs_to :location, MyApp.Location
end
```

Then on your `profile_table` migration you would have:

> add :location_id, references(:locations)

You don't need a foreign key on the location model, only the profile model.